# Dual boot error: this computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04

Trying to add Ubuntu to Windows 10 on my brand new laptop.

I use a ISO-based USB created with Rufus 2.10. However, every time when I try to install Ubuntu it crashes and returns "this computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining".

[image]

Any idea on what may cause this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: So on which part of the installation processes does it crash? Can you boot into the USB? Can you create the partitions, can you choose the space between Windows and Ubuntu? Or does it crash when you in the middle of the installation?

Comment: It crashes in the middle of installation at random moment.